# Selenium Unable to Locate Class Elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning how to use Selenium with Python and have been toying around with a few different things. I keep having an issue where I cannot locate any classes. I am able to locate and print data by xpath, but I cannot locate the classes.

The goal of this script is to gather a number from the table on the website and the current time, then append the items to a CSV file.

Site: https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses.html

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated as I am new to python. Thank you.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
    import pandas as pd
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import csv
    from datetime import datetime
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    #Open ChromeDriver
    PATH = ('/Users/brandon/Desktop/chromedriver')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    driver.get("https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-dogecoin-addresses.html")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()

    #Creates the Time
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    #####

    #Identify the section of page
    page = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'table table-condensed bb')
    time.sleep(3)

    #Gather the data

    for page in pages():

    num_of_wallets = page.find_element(By.XPATH, 
    "//html/body/div[5]/table[1]/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]").text
    table_dict = {"Time":current_time,
            "Wallets":num_of_wallets}
    file = open('dogedata.csv', 'a')

    try:
        file.write(f'{current_time},{num_of_wallets}')
    finally:
        file.close()
```

Comment: @Prophet Your edit have broken the indentation.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I only changed the ''' to ``` there.

Comment: Generally, partial edits are fowned upon. Had the edit been in Review queue, it would have been _Rejected_. If at all curators are editing, the edits must be complete in all respects.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Prophet didn't break the indentation, it was not indented from the start. You can look at the edit history to see that. Perhaps you should do some investigation before accusing someone falsely.

Comment: @JeffC Reread my above comment. Perhaps I explained much more.

Comment: If you would have included the error message (and read it yourself), I think it would have been clear. At least it would have given you a starting place for googling the error message. This question has been asked and answered many times before. You are putting multiple classes in your `.find_by()`. `table table-condensed bb` is actually 3 classes in CSS, `table`, `table-condensed`, and `bb`.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I read all comments several times, including both of yours. That doesn't make your first comment any less incorrect. Perhaps you should aim your comment at OP since they are the ones that didn't post correctly indented code, which is especially important in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table table-condensed bb` actually contains 3 class names.
So the best way to locate element based on multiple class names is to use css selector or xpath like:

```py
page = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.table.table-condensed.bb')
```

or

```py
page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='table table-condensed bb']")
```

Comment: While it will work the last way (passing more than one class in as a malformed CSS locator), I would not recommend that. To me that's more of a bug in `.find_element()` that it allows that. What you pass in only works because it's converted to a CSS selector and will likely confuse future readers. I highly recommend you remove that portion of your otherwise good answer.

Comment: @JeffC I agree with you! However I saw some users with a very high reputation mentioning that way too, so I thought it will make the answer more complete.